# Rails : url rewriting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url-rewriting

I have a rails 3 application in which users can find objects near them by tapping their address or by clicking on links I generates (looks like "Find objects in Dallas").

For the second way, I generates URLs like this :

```
www.my_website.com/search?place=Dallas
```

How can I transform these URLs to looks like this :

```
www.my_website.com/search/Dallas
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It all has to do with the routes you set up.

routes.rb

```
get 'search/:place' => 'search_controller#search', :as => :seo_search
```

Use it as such

```
seo_search_path('Dallas')
```

From your controller you will get a params[:place] available.

Comment: It works but there is an issue. All my methods name in search_controller are now count as town name.

For exemple `list_items_search_path` will produce => `/search/list_items` and so `list_item` will be count as a town name

Comment: Problem solved, just place the new routes below the old routes